# Updating a variable with a Javascript function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble updating the value of a variable `q` with a javascript function.  I have a timer that starts when "play" is pressed, and then continuously fires the current demand function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#main_video").on(
    "timeupdate", 
    function(event){
      currentDemand(this.currentTime);
    });
}); 

// Initiate Demand
var q = 0;

function currentDemand(currentTime){

    console.log(currentTime);

    if ( 0 <= currentTime < 10) {
        q === 0;
    }
    else if ( 10 <= currentTime < 12.5 || 57.5 <= 60) {
        q === 1;
    }
    else if ( 12.5 <= currentTime < 17.5 || 55 <= currentTime < 57.5) {
        q === 2;
    }
    else if ( 17.5 <= currentTime < 20 || 50 <= currentTime < 55) {
        q === 3;
    }
    else if (20 <= currentTime < 25 || 47.5 <= currentTime < 50) {
        q === 4;
    }
    else if ( 25 <= currentTime < 27.5 || 45 <= currentTime < 47.5 ) {
        q === 5;
    }
    else if ( 27.5 <= currentTime < 32.5 || 42500 <= currentTime < 45 ) {
        q === 6;
    }
    else if ( 32.5 <= currentTime < 35 || 40 <= currentTime < 42.5 ) {
        q === 7;
    }
    else if ( 45 <= currentTime < 47.5 ) {
        q === 8;
    }

    console.log(q);
    $("#currentDemand").text(q);
}
```

`currentTime` is logging correctly at values that should put it in the intervals, but `q` is not being set.  It probably has something to do with the scope, I just can't figure out how to fix it so that `q` is updated correctly and put into the `#currentDemand` div.

How can I set `q` to update?

Comment: You are not applying/assigning the value but comparing(`strict`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way to test if `currentTime` is between two values:

```
else if ( 10 <= currentTime < 12.5 || 57.5 <= 60) {
```

It's parsed as if you'd written:

```
else if ( ((10 <= currentTime) < 12.5) || (57.5 <= 60)) {
```

Since `57.5` is always less than `60`, the entire expression will always be true. But `10 <= currentTime < 12.5` is also always true, because `10 <= currentTime` is either `true` or `false`, and they're converted to `1` or `0` when comparing with another number. And both 1 and 0 are less than 12.5.

It should be written as:

```
else if ( (10 <= currentTime && currentTime < 12.5) || (57.5 <= currentTime && currentTime < 60) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use one equal `=` for **[assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment_2)** purpose, the both double `==` and triple `===` equals are used for **[comparaison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators)**.

Also you should separate your condition to looks like :

```
if ( currentTime >= 0 && currentTime < 10) {
    q = 0;
}
else if ( currentTime >= 10 && currentTime < 12.5 || 57.5 <= 60) {
//__________________________________________________^__________^ 
//this condition should be removed because it return always true
    q = 1;
}
else
.....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, q is still logging zero as time goes on.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You should fix also the conditions.. check my update.

Answer (score 0):

`q = whatevernumber;`

not `q === whatevernumber`, which returns a boolean

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, q is still logging zero as time goes on.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Break apart this: 0 <= currentTime < 10 into two comparisons ( 0 <= currentTime && currentTime < 10), otherwise current time is always greater than zero so it always returns true. The < 10 is ignored.

Answer (score -1):

To assign a value, you must only use one `=` if you use `==` or `===` are comparative. More info here:

[Assigment](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp)

[Comparative](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, q is still logging zero as time goes on.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that if changes '===' inside if statement it still returns zero? Try to insert a console.log() inside if to check where enters